# iPhone url scheme with content body to SMS

Tags: iphone, ios, url-scheme

I'm a Java/Web developer and I don't know anything about iPhone applications.
I did search on the Internet and the following steps are what I think people suggested but I want to confirm.
I would like to know if the following steps will allow me to send a content body to SMS messages when a user clicks on a link on a web page.

1. Build an iPhone app that takes content body and receiver phone number.
2. Make the visitors to my webpage download the iPhone app in #1 (using javascript to check if s/he already has it and a custom url scheme to open the iPhone version of "PlayStore")
3. The visitor installs the app.
4. Call the iPhone app in #1 using a custom URL scheme, from a link on a web page. This link contains the phone number of the receiver and a content body
5. The iPhone app in #1 then opens the native SMS app in iPhone, this time with a body.

Is this 
1. possible ?
2. the right way to do ?
**EDIT :** 
To make things clearer, what I need are...

1. It shouldn't be the web server that sends the SMS. The client who gave us the job does not want to pay for that. The client wants each visitor send their own SMS and pay for it.
2. I made a mistake. The phone number of the receiver should be empty. Only the content body is pre populated. So if I clicked on the "send SMS to my friends" link(on a webpage), it opens the native SMS application.(at least, this is how it works on android devices currently). And then the visitor would type in or select the phone number of the receiver from the contacts on his device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot open the SMS app with a message body.  The only way to send it is by using `MFMessageComposeViewController` (iOS 5.0+) as shown in [this page.](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-how-to-send-in-app-sms/)  If you need to support earlier versions, you are out of luck.

I'm not sure that Javascript can "check" that the device can run a url scheme either (I'm almost certain it can't check what apps are installed), but I'm not an expert at that kind of stuff.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, MFMessageComposeViewController was what I was referring to as the iPhone app #1. I don't know exactly what MFMessageComposeViewController is but isn't this an Objective-C thing that could only run on an iPhone. So I would have to write an iPhone app ?

Comment: You are confusing me.  What are you downloading from the AppStore then if it is not an iPhone app?

Comment: ok, the app that uses MFMessageComposeViewController on the inside ?

Comment: Yes, you could open the app with a URL scheme from your server, and then have the app itself handle opening the controller.

Comment: Could this app that uses MFMessageComposeViewController, then send SMS ?

Comment: That's the purpose of MFMessageComposeViewController.  You are talking about an app that you are making right?  Not someone else's app?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm not sure if im getting it right but basically what you mean is I can make my own app that can handle a content body and send an SMS, right ?

Comment: Yes, that is what your original question said.  You can't open an SMS with a message via URL scheme.

Answer (score 1):

As far as you are launching your application with some data using `Custom URL Schemes` this might help you calling your app with some parameters

http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

For step `#5` its not possible

Comment: So, in the end it is 'myapp' that sends SMS ?

Comment: Yes in the end you should send message by using `MFMessageComposeViewController`

Answer (score 0):

Short Answers:

1. No.
2. No. The "right" version would be to send the SMS from your webserver, using something like NowSMS.